# Linq groupby and count operations in mvc

Tags: linq

So here is my table

```
MyCourse (MyCourseID, CourseNumber, CourseName, SemesterName, Year)
```

Now if the table consists of the following data

```
ENG1200 'Basic English' Spring 2011
ENG1200 'Basic English' Spring 2011
```

I am simply trying to extract the count along with the CourseNumber as follows

```
ENG1200 'Basic English' Spring 2011 2
```

and then insert it into a new strongly typed class so I can use it in my View.
But the linq statement prints every class with a count of 1 on each.

```
ENG1200 'Basic English' Spring 2011 1
ENG1200 'Basic English' Spring 2011 1
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my linq code that I am using:

```
 public IQueryable<VotedCourses> GetVoted_Courses()
    {

        var votedCourses = courseDB.MyCourses.GroupBy
            (x => new
            {
                x.MyCourseID,
                x.CourseNumber,
                x.CourseName,
                x.SemesterName,
                x.Year
            })
            .Select(x =>
             new VotedCourses
             {
                 MyCourseID = x.Key.MyCourseID,
                 CourseNumber = x.Key.CourseNumber,
                 CourseName = x.Key.CourseName,
                 SemesterName = x.Key.SemesterName,
                 Year = x.Key.Year,
                 VoteCount = x.Count()
             });
        return votedCourses;
    }
```

Comment: Is MyCourseID the primary key? If it is, you shouldn't include it in the GroupBy, since it will be different for all rows

Comment: Yup, you guys are both right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice you're including `x.MyCourseID` in your anonymous type. This column isn't present in your samples, and it looks like an identity. My guess is that this column is different between the two records. I'd remove it from the type and try again.

Comment: Thanks Justin! MyCourseID is the primary key and thus different for each record. Removing it produced the desired result..